# I can not activate virtual environment in conda

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I create a virtual environment with conda

```
$ conda create test_env numpy .....
```

It gets created successfully.

```
$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/myname/anaconda3
my_project_env           /home/myname/anaconda3/envs/my_project_env
test_env                 /home/myname/anaconda3/envs/test_env
```

but I can not activate it

```
$ source activate my_project_env
```

returns - activate: No such file or directory

The only place I find *activate* is within the whole anaconda3 is in /common folder

```
source anaconda3/envs/my_project_env/lib/python3.6/venv/scripts/common/activate my_project_env
```

When I run it with this path I get **VENV_PROMPT** "kind of environment" but when I check libraries with *pip list* it returns a global list of installed libraries instead of the selected few.

```
$ source anaconda3/envs/my_project_env/lib/python3.6/venv/scripts/common/activate my_project_env
__VENV_PROMPT__myname@box:~$ pip3 list
```

Comment: sounds like your PATH variable is munged up.

Comment: @PaulH wouldn't it worked when I specified it in a command? Where should I expect to find activate file? is it normal for it to be in scripts/commons instead of anaconda3/bin/ any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: What version of conda do you have? The new way to activate environments is `conda activate env_name`

Comment: IIRC, the `activate` script should be in a central locations. not in the environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I met with the same problem. It is because I have changed the system's $PATH variable from anaconda's main bin directory to the environment's bin directory. Actually, the activate's path is under /home/users/anaconda3/bin/. So I just use the following command to make a link between the two bin directories:

```
ln -s /home/userName/anaconda3/bin/activate /home/userName/anaconda3/envs/envName/bin/activate
ln -s /home/userName/anaconda3/bin/deactivate /home/userName/anaconda3/envs/envName/bin/deactivate
```

Comment: I followed the instruction. But, I got this message( `bash: In: command not found`) and nothing happened. :(((

Comment: Sorry, it is actually `ln` means making links.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this command activate your conda environment:

```
source activate /home/myname/anaconda3/envs/my_project_env
```

Recommended command to create environment with python version 2.7 :

```
conda create -n my_project_env python=2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your conda version

```
conda -V
```

Create virtual environment for your project

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda
```

To activate your virtual environment

```
source activate yourenvname
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it may be a PATH issue. However, if you're still able to run other `conda` commands then you may need to either `conda update conda` or delete conda and reinstall. In my case, I was running miniconda which I believe simply did not contain the `activate` binary.

Running `conda activate` instead of `source activate` solved my issues.